# CSS not applying in View unless toggled

Tags: css, model-view-controller, razor

In my View of my MVC app, I have some inline CSS as well as some from a style sheet in the head of the shared page.

When the page loads, some of my CSS is not applied. If I inspect the page, and go to the elements and toggle them off then back on, they work. When I initially inspect the individual elements, they all appear to be correct, and hierarchy is "working" as expected.

Console Error: Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: by toggle you mean in jquery?

Comment: if so, maybe your CSS selectors (in the stylesheet) are the problem

Comment: @Adina Toggle in the Dev Tools, Turned out there was an error I didn't see that it was suppressing inline CSS

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a console error, that the inline CSS was being suppressed.

Moved all CSS into a style sheet and resolved the issue